# RBAC Concept based on SQL Database

Tags: sql, rbac

I am trying to build a little RBAC concept based on a SQL Database. I have multiple groups and every group can have access to n APIs. Furthermore every group can trigger actions based on the Scope.

I tried it with Solution 1 but here I have the issue that the permissions for a group with all scopes are equal. I can't distinguish like Group1 with Scope1 can do Actions xyz, Group1 with Scope2 can do Actions xyz. Based on that issue, I came up with Solution 2. It seems to work but I'm not sure if that is a "good" design. Maybe you have some helpful hints to do this better. Thanks in advance! [RBAC Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvsvs.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question - preferably as editable text